# How can I troubleshoot what is causing pytest to time out?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm running some test on an app that is listening on multiple ports using pytest.  All of my tests pass except one test that times out because these tests are being run in a Gitlab CI-pipeline. When it times out I get no output from pytest. Is there any way to get at least some troubleshooting data from pytest while the test is running to see why it is taking so long?

How I am currently running the test:

```
python3 -m pytest -vvv /tests
```

The test itself:

```
def send_tcp(hostname, port, message, protocol=socket.SOCK_STREAM):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, protocol)
    s.connect((hostname, int(port)))
    s.sendall(bytes(message, "utf-8"))
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    s.close()


def send_tcp_TLS(hostname, port, message):
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL
    context.check_hostname = False
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile="rootCA.crt")
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=hostname)
    ssl_sock.connect((hostname, port))
    ssl_sock.sendall(bytes(message, "utf-8"))
    ssl_sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    ssl_sock.close()


def receive(message):
    r = redis.Redis(host="redis-input", port=6378)
    found = False
    timeout = time.time() + 20
    while not found and time.time() < timeout:
        for value in r.lrange("inq", 0, -1):
            decoded = value.decode("utf-8")
            parsed = json.loads(decoded)
            if message in parsed["raw"]:
                found = True
        if not found:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    assert found


def send_and_receive(hostname, port, message, protocol=socket.SOCK_STREAM, tls=False):
    if tls:
        send_tcp_TLS(hostname, port, message)
    else:
        send_tcp(hostname, port, message, protocol)
    receive(message.rstrip())

def test_z_tls():
    send_and_receive("test-z-tls", 20516, "Test TLS z message", tls=True)
```

Because my test works with other ports with and without tls, I don't think the test is the issue.

I added a -vvv flag to pytest to get the maximum amount of verbosity but I still don't see what is happening during the test itself.

Comment: You know about the `-s` flag? So with `python -m pytest -s` makes it possible to use print statements in your code. Could this help you?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. It should be why `send_and_receive()` takes too much time, along with a [mcve]. You basically omitted the code that is at the core of the issue.

Comment: I've added more of the code.  The end goal is that I want to find out why it is so slow but I don't expect someone to troubleshoot all of this. What I want is to just know how to get more information out of pytest.

Comment: That's still not a [mcve]. You can use a debugger to at least estimate the time something takes. There's also a `timeit` module or something like that. Check DNS as something that requires time, too. What is even the time this takes? And what do you expect?

Comment: For one of the other ports running tls, the time it takes is less than 10 seconds.  That's the same as the ports that are not running tls. If the port is closed or not responding, then I would prefer that the test would just fail, not hang. If try it with a port that I know is not open, it does fail every time.

Answer (score 0):

Set the desired timeout

```
def send_tcp_TLS(hostname, port, message):
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL
    context.check_hostname = False
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile="rootCA.crt")
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(10) # <<< timeout
    ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=hostname)
    ssl_sock.connect((hostname, port))
    ssl_sock.sendall(bytes(message, "utf-8"))
    ssl_sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    ssl_sock.close()
```